# Is there a 'compare' option when using WP_Query apart from meta_query

Tags: wp-query

I understand the use of `compare` in the context of `meta-query`, but I'd like to know if it's possible to do a `compare` on another column in the `wp_posts` table via `WP_Query`. I wrote this first, which works fine:

```
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            'SELECT id, post_title, post_name  
             FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts
             WHERE post_type = %s  
             AND post_status = %s
             AND post_title REGEXP "%s"
             ORDER BY post_date ASC',
             'post',
             'publish',
             'Daily Task:'
        )  
    );
```

but in trying to let WordPress do the work, I would like something like this:

```
    $results = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'     => 'post_date',
        'relation'    => 'AND',
        array ( 'compare'     => 'LIKE%',
                'post_title'  => 'Daily Task: '
              )
        )
    );
```

I've searched the Interwebs and the Codex and all I find are references to `meta_query`. Is that because `compare`, `LIKE`, or `REGEXP` doesn't apply to `WP_Query`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if it's possible to do a `compare` on another column
> in the `wp_posts` table via `WP_Query`

In [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), `compare` is not part of the direct/top-level [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/), and it's only (by default) used with custom field (or post meta) and date queries (i.e. clauses in `meta_query` and `date_query`), and the [`comment_count` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#comment-parameters).

So basically, the answer is "no", or not by default.

#### But it can be made possible using `posts_where` and other hooks in `WP_Query`.

> I wrote this first, which works fine

Yes, I believe so.

However, `WP_Query` provides various hooks for modifying the SQL query, so instead of making the direct SQL query (using `$wpdb`), you can use hooks like [`posts_where`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/) and [`posts_clauses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/).

Here's an example based on your `new WP_Query()` call, which queries for posts where the title starts with a specific phrase:

```php
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where', 10, 2 );
function my_posts_where( $where, $query ) {
    if ( $value = $query->get( 'custom_param' ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $like = $wpdb->esc_like( $value ) . '%';
        $where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '$like'";
    }

    return $where;
}

// In your template or code:
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'custom_param' => 'Daily Task:',
    // .. other args
) );
```

But of course, you don't have to use that code or that if you believe direct SQL query is better in your case, then just go with it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming there is no native functionality in WP_Query for `LIKE` or `REGEXP.` I'll stick with the mere 11 lines shown in my original post that did the job perfectly. I tucked it into a shortcode so users can easily pop it into a post. Of course, all this would be for not if they had used a category, because that you can filter with WP_Query.

Comment: Sure, but nonetheless, I thought I should revise my answer - and hopefully it's better worded now.

Comment: Yes! Your edited question brings a lot of clarity. But also some more learning on my part. Back to the Codex

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and I'd be happier if you think my answer worth a +1 for confirming the "is it possible/doable" part in your question... But anyway, happy learning/coding! :)